# how to make advance level test planning (scripting) with scenario

Tags: testing, jmeter

I want to do testing according to following scenarios.

1) I want to ramp up users login to my application from 1 to 25 users in increments of 5 every 2 minutes. (I have achieved this through concurrency thread group)

2) Once we reach 50 users, have 5 users expanding defect donut and 10 users expanding release quadrant, 5 users clicking on defect details and 5 users logout.

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally people use different [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to represent different groups of users doing different business operations.

If for some reason you need to stick to single Thread Group you can consider the following configuration elements:

- [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) - allows to define how often will be affected sampler(s) executed in percentage of or total executions
- [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) - allows defining children samplers execution basing on some form of [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for detailed information on configuration with examples.

You may also find [Weighted Switch Controller](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WeightedSwitchController/) useful, however it marked as an "experimental" feature therefore use it with caution.

Comment: thanku sir,

It solved my problem.